# GetItems(cQuery)

Tags: splistitem

The following code seems to be working. Basically, I have multiple items in a document library and I need to run a cleanup PS. Do I need to add Dispose as I am not running under the Using context?

```
$webUrl = "http://Biochemistry.Lab.UOF/Sites/Research"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["CurrentResearch"]

$caml = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=`"ResearchName`" /><Value Type=`"Text`">DNA PCR Test</Value></Contains></Where>"
$cQuery=new-object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery"
$cQuery.Query = $caml
$myItems=null

$myItems = $list.GetItems($cQuery);
Write-Host ("Items returned = [" + $myItems.Count + "]")

if ($myItems.Count -gt 1)
{
for ($i=1; $i -le $myItems.Count; $i++)     
{
   if($i -ne 0)
   {                
      $myItems[$i].Delete();
      Write-Host "Deleted ";
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Mike, instead of editing the answer into your question.. can you please post an answer instead? Currently, no one can see what you asked originally (without going to version history). If you post it as an answer people can upvote it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working version.

```
$webUrl = "http://Biochemistry.Lab.UOF/Sites/Research"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["CurrentResearch"]

$caml = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=`"ResearchName`" /><Value Type=`"Text`">DNA PCR Test</Value></Contains></Where>"
$cQuery=new-object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery"
$cQuery.Query = $caml
$myItems=null

$myItems = $list.GetItems($cQuery);
Write-Host ("Items returned = [" + $myItems.Count + "]")

if ($myItems.Count -gt 1)
{
for ($i=1; $i -le $myItems.Count; $i++)     
{
   if($i -ne 0)
   {                
      $myItems[$i].Delete();
      Write-Host "Deleted ";
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SPQuery has a propery named RowLimit. Do you get the expected result when setting this property value to 1?

Comment: The code is working. Do I need to add Dispose method at the end?

Comment: Yes, dispose the SPWeb: $web

Comment: i changed the for loop for ($i=0; $i -le $myItems.Count-1; $i++)  now I dont get an error but it only deletes 2 files. Total count is 5 and I need to delete 4 of the items.